# PL/SQL How to select n-1 values?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
    hour_in number:=4;
    minute_in number:=59;
    sek_in number:=45;
    together_in number;
    sat varchar(10):='G6';
    M0 number;
begin
    kopa_in:=((sek_in/60)+minute_in)/60+hour_in;

    select M0 into M0 
    from jsm_nav 
    where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in 
    and prn=sat;

    select delta_n into deltan 
    from jsm_nav 
    where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in 
    and prn=sat;
end;
```

This only works if there is only one value that is lower than `together_in`! I need to select `n-1` value, if we assume that `together_in` is `n` value!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean you want "n - 1" values?  You can only put one into a variable.

An easy way to get one value without changing the query very much is to use `min()` or `max()`:

```
select min(M0) into M0 from jsm_nav where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in and prn=sat;
select min(delta_n) into deltan from jsm_nav where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in and prn=sat;
```

Of course, you don't need two queries to do this:

```
select min(M0),min(delta_n) into M0, jsm_nav
from jsm_na
where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in and prn=sat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the given query

```
and rownum < together_in;
```

Be sure together_in is well initialized

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT INTO` requires one and only one row. You should limit the number of rows returned by your queries.

One way to do this is using `ROWNUM`:

```
select M0 into M0 from (select M0 from jsm_nav where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in and prn=sat order by ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda desc) where rownum = 1;
select delta_n into deltan from (select delta_n from jsm_nav where ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda<together_in and prn=sat order by ((sekunde/60)+minute)/60+stunda desc) where rownum = 1;
```

I used a combination of `ROWNUM` and `ORDER BY ... DESC` so that you get exactly one row (the row that is closest to `together_in`).